# JUnit4 TextUtils.isEmpty() gives different result than String.isEmpty()

Tags: java, android, string, junit, is-empty

I know it's weird, but this is what I have.

[image]

I'm writing a unit test to check my logic for an Android application. During the test execution, I see that it fails on that line:

`if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fromFile))`

Before that `if` statement fromFile is equals to `""` (empty string), but somehow it passes over it and breaks with another logic that doesn't expect empty string.

Diving into debug I saw that `fromFile.isEmpty()` returns correct result, but `TextUtils.isEmpty(fromFile)` says that it's not empty.

Open source code, i see:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
   if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

and String.java:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
   return value.length == 0;
}
```

I have following configutation: 
jdk 1.8.0_77

I would like to avoid whole logic in the app to support String.isEmpty() just to pass the test, since I need to support code before Android API 9, where `String.isEmpty` is not available, and also `TextUtils.isEmpty()` do more.
Any help with clarification and suggesttions would be helpful.

Has anyone faced it? How should I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone who will face it in future:

I have figured out this by the help of good man, that it is related to android unit test configuration in gradle:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Which pointed me to a solution: get rid of android dependencies in you buisness logic that you are testing with JUnit(unit test).

I simply replaced `android.text.TextUtils` with my own method that is in `MyStringUtils.java` class, that does the same.

Problem was that by deault Android methods did return deafult values while running unit test, and it didn't actually check `fromFile` value itself, rather then return stub/default value.

Comment: But is this a solution? I mean for this case you have only TextUtils, but what if you use SparsArrays and some other custom utility implementation provided by Android?

Comment: the idea of pure JUnit tests is that they have to be used against POJO (Plain Old Java Object). `SparseArrays` are not Old Java. If you have it, you can go with http://robolectric.org/, which is totally fine according to google https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 5):

`TextUtils` isn't a JUnit method. If you need to manipulate with `TextUtils.isEmpty` answer or other method, you can mock it like:

```
mockStatic(TextUtils.class);
when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any(CharSequence.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            CharSequence str = (CharSequence) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

---

Don't forget to add `TextUtils` to `PrepareForTest` list:

```
@PrepareForTest({TextUtils.class})
```

Also above mentioned method works for `returnDefaultValues` configuration:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use `Powermock` and `mockStatic` is not applicable. We moved to the different architecture, where our Java classes are POJO and don't have any android dependencies. We also moved away from static methods like 'Utils.doSomething' and removing singletons. This gives us more control of DI and test coverage. 

As far as I know codecov still doesn't support `PowerMockito`.

But thank you for your answer, I guess a lot of devs will find it useful as well.